# Unity: 2d GameObject Ricochet

Tags: unity-game-engine

How can I make a 2D GameObject Ricochet off a wall or surface with the same angle it used to hit it? Can you just point me to the right direction or how I should do it?

Comment: Use the physics material and set it's bounciness property to 1.

Comment: Are you using RigidBody? Are you moving your object through forces or assigning it's position directly?

Comment: Sorry I am replying just now. Yeah I am moving the object through addforce for rigidbodies

Answer (score 0):

Create your bouncing game object as a sprite. Add a 2D collider component and a rigidbody2D component.  Add a physics material into the material property of the rigidbody and adjust settings to taste.  Your object should move with physics and bounce off things when it collides with them.